# Specific order of divs

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the order of divs on my site like on the image:
[image]

On the top part of image the red div should be floated to left and blue and green to right. Important for me is to have green div below blue, no matter what size of red div is, so `clear: both` is not fine. I tried with flexbox but also with no success. I also tried wrapping blue and green div in another div, name it `rightColumn` but then I am not able to achieve the lower part of image: on mobile devices (I know `media only` CSS rule so this is fine) I want to have this order: blue, red, green, each of 100% width.

How to achieve that in pure CSS? Is it even possible?

Comment: Don't think in `floats`, but think in `grid` for your desktop, and `flex` for your mobile layout. On mobile your can use `order` to ensure you get the order you way, on desktop a combo of `grid-template` and `grid-area` to place them in your responsive grid.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `grid` and reset `order` and `grid-template-columns` for bigger screen.

here is an example with a break point at 768px *(i used html5 tags elements for the demo, but feel free to use your own markup and class/ids )*

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  gap: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  section {
    grid-template-columns: 60% 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  }
  main {
    order: -1;
    grid-row: auto /span 2;/*(auto or 1) /  span as many rows that you have elements to stand in second column */
  }
}


/* colors */

body {
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: #004488
}

main {
  background: #FF0000
}

footer {
  background: #0A8800;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>#004488 </header>
  <main> #FF0000 </main>
  <footer>#0A8800 </footer>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

A mix of CSS grids and flexbox for mobile should accomplish this:

```js
const main = document.querySelector( 'main' );

// To simulate mobile behaviour
document.body.addEventListener( 'click', event => {
  
  main.classList.toggle( 'mobile' );
  
})
```

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "red blue" auto
    "red green" auto
   / auto 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
#red {
  width: 65vw;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  grid-area: red;
  order: 1;
}
#blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  grid-area: blue;
  order: 2;
}
#green {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  grid-area: green;
  order: 3;
}

.mobile {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.mobile #red {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="blue"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
</main>
```

You can change the order on the mobile version (which you should stick into a `@media` query, but it's stack overflow so for safety I simulated it with a class instead) by modifying the `order` property, and on desktop, you can do it by changing the values of the columns or rows in the `grid-template`.

Docs for `grid-template`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template
Docs for `order`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: I don't think you should specifically use the grid for desktop and flex for mobile. In fact, using media, queries you could just change the same grid to a different layout. In this specific case, it would be smarter to push the grid for the desktop inside a media query to overwrite the default mobile block behavior. There I no need to use Flexbox for something that the normal block behavior would solve by default.

Comment: It depends on whether he wanted to change the order. What you mention is fine, there isn’t a rule to use flex on mobile (though gap is quite useful and not default block behaviour). Either way, it provides a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `order:1` (order CSS property) by applying flex to its parent.

Note: If you want to use Bootstrap then it will be very smooth.
[Bootstrap Orders](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/)

For more detail please refer to this link [CSS Order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to grid would be using flex with display contents:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  width: 60%;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.column {
  width: 35%;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .column {
    display: contents;
  }
  .red {
    order: 2;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .blue {
    order: 1;
  }
  .green {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red">red</div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="blue">blue</div>
    <div class="green">green</div>
  </div>
</div>
```